# How to combine all child elements under their parent's key

Tags: node.js, sqlite, rest

I am trying to build a simple API in node js using express and sqlite. I have this database:

```
id | book_no | paragraph_no | word_no |  word
---------------------------------------------
 1 |       1 |            1 |       1 | hello
 2 |       1 |            1 |       2 |   how
 3 |       1 |            1 |       3 |   are
 4 |       1 |            1 |       4 |   you
 5 |       1 |            2 |       1 |     i
 6 |       1 |            2 |       2 |    am
 7 |       1 |            2 |       3 |  fine
```

And this is my code:

```
app.get("/paragraph/:number/:from-:till", (req, res, next) => {

  var paragraph = req.params.number, from = req.params.from, till = req.params.till;

  var words_query = 
    `SELECT * FROM words WHERE book_no = ${paragraph} 
     AND paragraph_no >= ${from} AND paragraph_no <= ${till}`;

  db.all(words_query, [], (err, data) => {
    
    res.status(200).json(
      { data }
    );
  
  });

});
```

When I make a GET request to `/paragraph/1/1-2` I get this output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "book_no": 1,
            "paragraph_no": 1,
            "word_no": 1,
            "word": "hello"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "book_no": 1,
            "paragraph_no": 1,
            "word_no": 2,
            "word": "how"
        },

        // rest of the words from paragraph 1

        {
            "id": 5,
            "book_no": 1,
            "paragraph_no": 2,
            "word_no": 1,
            "word": "i"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "book_no": 1,
            "paragraph_no": 2,
            "word_no": 2,
            "word": "am"
        }
        
        // rest of the words from paragraph 2

    ]
}
```

As you can see, all the words are combined and are one after another. But what I need is to seperate them using the paragraph_no key. So for example:

```
{
    
    "data": {

        "1": [
            
            {
                "id": 1,
                "book_no": 1,
                "paragraph_no": 1,
                "word_no": 1,
                "word": "hello"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "book_no": 1,
                "paragraph_no": 1,
                "word_no": 2,
                "word": "how"
            },

            // rest of the words from paragraph 1

        ],

        "2": [

            {
                "id": 5,
                "book_no": 1,
                "paragraph_no": 2,
                "word_no": 1,
                "word": "i"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "book_no": 1,
                "paragraph_no": 2,
                "word_no": 2,
                "word": "am"
            },
            
            // rest of the words from paragraph 2
            
        ]

    }

}
```

What can I change in my code to have my desired results? I tried doing this:

```
res.status(200).json(
  { 
    paragraph_no: data 
  }
);
```

But that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your query is open to a SQL injection attack.  Please make sure you use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looping through the list and generating the object yourself.

```
var result = {};

data.forEach(o => {
    // See if you already have the paragraph
    if(!result[o.paragraph_no]) {
        // Add a new paragraph to the result object
        result[o.paragraph_no] = [];
    }

    // Add the DB row to the paragraph array
    result[o.paragraph_no].push(o);
})

res.status(200).json({ data: result })
```

Comment: Hey thanks this worked! And yes I need to make it secure from SQL injection. I had a similar question desiring a slightly different layout. Can I ask you here, edit the main question or make a new post? Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest a new post to make sure others are able to find the solution, should they have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way i can think off is to just loop over them and add them back:

```js
app.get("/paragraph/:number/:from-:till", (req, res, next) => {

    var paragraph = req.params.number, from = req.params.from, till = req.params.till;

    var words_query =
        `SELECT * FROM words WHERE book_no = ${paragraph} 
       AND paragraph_no >= ${from} AND paragraph_no <= ${till}`;

    db.all(words_query, [], (err, data) => {
        let parsed_data = {}
        for (let word_obj of data) {
            //if the array does not exsit yet make it 
            if (!parsed_data[word_obj.paragraph_no]) parsed_data[word_obj.paragraph_no] = []
            //add the word_obj to it
            parsed_data[word_obj.paragraph_no].push(word_obj)
        }

        res.status(200).json(
            { parsed_data }
        );

    });

});
```

Comment: Hey thanks this too worked for me! Really appreciate it.

Comment: nice ( i posted this and then i saw it was already answerd :P )